# Traversing through a generic binary tree

Tags: java, generics, binary-tree

An abstract binary tree is to be created using a generic class. Each node has a string value as well as an initialCalculatedValue value. No changes should be made to the main class and a static inner class is to be included in the generic class. I'd like some advice on my code, as the main class is giving me error on accessing 'timesVisited' and 'values'. My code can't seem to access those variables.

Main class code:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        WalkableTree<String, Integer> ast = new WalkableTree<>(0);

        WalkableTree.Node<String, Integer> plus = ast.setRoot("+");
        plus.setRightChild("20");

        WalkableTree.Node<String, Integer> multiply = plus.setLeftChild("*");
        multiply.setLeftChild("10");

        WalkableTree.Node<String, Integer> bracketedPlus = multiply.setRightChild("+");
        bracketedPlus.setLeftChild("3");
        bracketedPlus.setRightChild("4");

        // write visitor to display pre-order
        System.out.println("Pre-order traversal:");
        ast.walk(current -> {
            if(current.timesVisited == 2)
                System.out.print(current.value + " ");
        });
        System.out.println();

        // write visitor to display in-order
        System.out.println("In-order traversal:");
        ast.walk(current -> {
            if(current.timesVisited == 3)
                System.out.print(current.value + " ");
        });
        System.out.println();

        // write visitor to display post-order
        System.out.println("Post-order traversal:");
        ast.walk(current -> {
            if(current.timesVisited == 4)
                System.out.print(current.value + " ");
        });
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Functional interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Visitor<N> {
    public void visit(N node);
}
```

Generic class:

```
public class WalkableTree <T, R> {

     private T root = null;
     private R initialCalculatedValue;
     public static Node current;

    public WalkableTree(R initialCalculatedValue) {
        this.initialCalculatedValue = initialCalculatedValue;
    }

    public Node getRoot() {
        return (Node) root;
    }

    public Node setRoot(T value) {
        current = new Node(null,null,null,value,null,0);
        return current;
    }

    public R getInitialCalculatedValue() {
        return initialCalculatedValue;
    }

    public void setInitialCalculatedValue(R initialCalculatedValue) {
        this.initialCalculatedValue = initialCalculatedValue;
    }

    protected void reset(Node node) {
        node.timesVisited = 0;
        node.calculatedValue = initialCalculatedValue;
        reset((Node) node.leftChild);
        reset((Node) node.rightChild);
    }

    public Node nextNode(Node node) {
        node.timesVisited++;
        if(node.timesVisited == 1)
            return node;

        if(node.timesVisited == 2)
            return (Node) node.leftChild;

        if(node.timesVisited == 3)
            return (Node) node.rightChild;

        if(node.timesVisited == 4)
            return (Node) node.getParent();

        return node;
    }

    public void walk(Visitor visitor) {
        //Reset all the nodes in the tree
        reset((Node) root);

        //Set the current node to visit at the root of the tree
        visitor.visit(root);

        //Walking through the tree as long as the current node still exists
            //If current node exists, let the visitor object visit the current node
            //Current node is set to the next node using nextNode() method
        while (this.current == current)
        {
            nextNode(current);
        }
    }

    public static class Node<T, R> {
        //Variables
        Object leftChild;
        Object rightChild;
        Object parent;
        T value;
        R calculatedValue;
        int timesVisited = 0;

        public Node(Object leftChild, Object rightChild, Object parent, T value, R calculatedValue, int timesVisited) {
            this.leftChild = leftChild;
            this.rightChild = rightChild;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.value = value;
            this.calculatedValue = calculatedValue;
            this.timesVisited = timesVisited;
        }

        public Object getLeftChild() {
            return leftChild;
        }

        public Node setLeftChild(T value) {
            Node newLeft = new Node(null,null, current,value,0,0);
            current = newLeft;
            return current;
        }

        public Object getRightChild() {
            return rightChild;
        }

        public Node setRightChild(T value) {
            Node newRight = new Node(null,null, current,value,0,0);
            current = newRight;
            return current;
        }

        public Object getParent() {
            return parent;
        }

        public void setParent(Node parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public T getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public R getCalculatedValue() {
            return calculatedValue;
        }

        public void setCalculatedValue(R calculatedValue) {
            this.calculatedValue = calculatedValue;
        }

        public int getTimesVisited() {
            return timesVisited;
        }

        public void setTimesVisited(int timesVisited) {
            this.timesVisited = timesVisited;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need add the element type of your Visitor

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the method in WalkableTree as below:

```
 public void walk(Visitor<Node> visitor) {
        //Reset all the nodes in the tree
        reset((Node) root);

        //Set the current node to visit at the root of the tree
        visitor.visit((Node) root);

        //Walking through the tree as long as the current node still exists
        //If current node exists, let the visitor object visit the current node
        //Current node is set to the next node using nextNode() method
        while (this.current == current)
        {
            nextNode(current);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my error. However, now the contents of the lambdas in the Main class do not display any output on the console. Any suggestions as to why this could be?

Comment: So basically, I want to understand what are you trying to achieve. As I see the root node in your code isn't instantiated. It's always null. In the piece of code, you posted. And you are trying to rest the value of root.

Comment: Abstract syntax tree 'ast' is created in the main class. Thereafter, the program should display the contents of the tree respective to each of the three traversals. To do this, a visitor object should start or visit the root and traverse through the tree (method 'walk' in WalkableTree) by first resetting the trees nodes, getting to the root and then while this node is not null; go onto the next node. The nextnode method is where the next node will be returned based on the number of times the visitor object has been there, initially zero. It should print the value of that node before proceeding

Comment: The expected output should be Pre-order traversal: + * 10 + 3 4 20 In-order traversal: 10 * 3 + 4 + 20 Post-order traversal: 10 3 4 + * 20 +